# Problem with wifi in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04

Hi I have a problem in Ubuntu with WiFi. I have a WiFi extender and only with my computer I'm not able to connect to internet. It happens only when I'm connected through the extender. I've checked with Wireshark and apparently when the computer does the arp request, the router doesn't give the arp reply. I've tried also to ping the router but  I'm only able to ping devices directly connected to the extender and not the ones that are connected directly to the router. I think it's strange because the extender doesn't break the broadcast domain and with other devices I'm able to send ping also to the devices directly connected to the router.

Comment: But it happens only with my Ubuntu machine, my phone and my Mac don't have this problem.

Comment: What is Wi-Fi extender?

Comment: It's a TP-Link TL-WA830RE